# Example for $ f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ s.t. $f'$ has fulll rank but $f$ is not injective

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Is there an example of $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $f\in C^1$, $f'$ has full rank at any point $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ (the derivative matrix has non-zero determinant everywhere), but $f$ is not global injective?

I'm trying to find such example, but not sure if there even exists one, due to the inverse function theorem (although im pretty sure this theorem only talks about locally diffeomorphisms, so not sure again).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&\bigl(e^x\cos(y),e^x\sin(y)\bigr),\end{array}$$then $f'(p)$ is invertible, for every $p\in\Bbb R^2$. However, $f(0,0)=f(0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$$
$$f(z)=e^z$$

is a well known smooth map, with full rank at any point (it is a local diffeomorphism) but not injective. Indeed $f(z)=f(z+2\pi i)$ for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$.